# Has been raining vs Had been raining

Tags: verbs, perfect-aspect

*This question came in the Dhaka University admission exam 2002-03*

Q) It ____ raining since morning

(a) is

(b) was

(c) has been

(d) had been

My question bank says that the answer is (c). [An alternative question bank of DU vouches for my question bank](https://blog.learntube.academy/du-a-unit-admission-question-solution-2002-2003/#:%7E:text=It%20_____%20raining%20since%20morning.), and agrees that the answer is (c). I, however, feel that both (c) and (d) are acceptable.

[I did an Ngram query and found both being used.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had_INF%20been%20raining%20since%20morning&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t3%3B%2Chad_INF%20been%20raining%20since%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhad%20been%20raining%20since%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhas%20been%20raining%20since%20morning%3B%2Cc0)

Are both (c) and (d) correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are quite correct. (d) is possible.
As always, the choice depends on the context.

If you are speaking on the day in question,
**It has been raining since morning**.

But if you were referring back to an event in the past, eg:
**it had been raining since morning the day that his car went off the road.**
(d) is more appropriate.

The examiner is assuming that the answer relates to the day in question and not to a past event.